# Foreach loop not outputting arrays as expected

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an object called `Thread_category`. This has a method called `find_all_by_category($category)` which outputs an array of threads that have the category, `$category`.

I have an array `$category_array_for_this_thread` which outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => Allergic diseases [1] => Allergic asthma [2] => Congenital lung disease [3] => Idiopathic pulmonary fibrosis )
```

Now, if I do this

```
    $test1 = Thread_category::find_all_by_category('Allergic diseases');
    print_r($test1);
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";

    $test2 = Thread_category::find_all_by_category('Allergic asthma');
    print_r($test2);
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";

    $test3 = Thread_category::find_all_by_category('Congenital lung disease');
    print_r($test3);
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";

    $test4 = Thread_category::find_all_by_category('Idiopathic pulmonary fibrosis');
    print_r($test4);
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";
```

I get

```
Array ( [0] => Thread_category Object ( [id] => 2 [thread_id] => 145 [category] => Allergic diseases ) [1] => Thread_category Object ( [id] => 10 [thread_id] => 146 [category] => Allergic diseases ) [2] => Thread_category Object ( [id] => 20 [thread_id] => 147 [category] => Allergic diseases ) ) 

Array ( [0] => Thread_category Object ( [id] => 21 [thread_id] => 147 [category] => Asthma ) [1] => Thread_category Object ( [id] => 24 [thread_id] => 148 [category] => Allergic asthma ) ) 

Array ( [0] => Thread_category Object ( [id] => 4 [thread_id] => 145 [category] => Congenital lung disease ) [1] => Thread_category Object ( [id] => 22 [thread_id] => 147 [category] => Congenital lung disease ) [2] => Thread_category Object ( [id] => 25 [thread_id] => 148 [category] => Congenital lung disease ) ) 

Array ( [0] => Thread_category Object ( [id] => 5 [thread_id] => 145 [category] => Idiopathic pulmonary fibrosis ) [1] => Thread_category Object ( [id] => 11 [thread_id] => 146 [category] => Idiopathic pulmonary fibrosis ) )
```

BUT!

if I do this

```
        foreach($category_array_for_this_thread as $category){
                    echo $category . "<br/>";
        $test_array = Thread_category::find_all_by_category($category);
        print_r($test_array);
        }
```

I get this....

```
   Allergic diseases
   Array ( [0] => Thread_category Object ( [id] => 2 [thread_id] => 145 [category] =>    Allergic diseases ) [1] => Thread_category Object ( [id] => 10 [thread_id] => 146 [category] => Allergic diseases ) [2] => Thread_category Object ( [id] => 20 [thread_id] => 147 [category] => Allergic diseases ) ) 
   Allergic asthma
   Array ( ) 
   Congenital lung disease
   Array ( ) 
   Idiopathic pulmonary fibrosis
   Array ( )
```

The only difference I can see is that the second is in a foreach loop. Can someone explain to me why I am getting 3 empty arrays

Here is the method....

```
       public static function find_all_by_category($category) {
    return self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM thread_category WHERE category='{$category}'");
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the edit Floris..

Comment: Do your `find_all_by_category` method access to the global variable `$category` or `$category_array_for_this_thread`?

Comment: Can you echo $category to see what it is producing?  Maybe show more context of the code?

Comment: Johnny if I echo $category I get                             Allergic diseases
Allergic asthma
Congenital lung disease
Idiopathic pulmonary fibrosis

Comment: What if you use a different type of loop with the index value? edit:  maybe echo your sql.

Answer (score 0):

in foeach loop, your $category have just one value and other 3 could be empty or have anything else which returning no result on when it searched.

Comment: If you pass the individual values into the method as shown, there is an array outputted - i.e. there is a result. But when outputted from the foreach loop. I know its some obvious point of logic i'm missing but just can't see it......

Comment: Oh ! dear find_all_by_category saearched with exact words. do you got it?

Comment: if I output $category in the foreach loop I get Allergic diseases Allergic asthma Congenital lung disease Idiopathic pulmonary fibrosis i.e. the exact words. These are the same as those being passed into the method in the example given above (when done individually as opposed to the foreach loop) so this can't be the answer....

Comment: You got result for "Asthma" but as in your $category in 2nd iteration of foreach loop there is "Allergic asthma" for which you got empty array. on other hand you got results "Allergic diseases" individually and also in foreach becasue in foreach on 1st iteration exact word comes but on other three iterations exact words are not there...

Comment: I still wonder if you have invisible characters (spaces etc) in your array that you are not aware of. Try `echo '"'.$category.'"'.<br>;`. Also put four lines like `print_r(Thread_category::find_all_by_category('Allergic asthma'));` right in your loop. Does the function call work for the hard wired variable? Because if it does, it means your variable doesn't contain what you think. Otherwise I am out of ideas!

Answer (score 0):

The second element of your array has the value `Allergic` but you need it to have `Asthma`. Could it be that this throws your `find_all_by_category` function off - it explains why the second element is empty, and maybe the function does something strange after it has found no match?

Comment: I just added in an echo of $category into the loop to show whats being passed in. As far as I can see the $category is same between the two examples......argh!