# Ongoing unexplainable output from a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

OK so I posted this question earlier and it remains unanswered. I am grateful for the attempts though.

[Foreach loop not outputting arrays as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154132/foreach-loop-not-outputting-arrays-as-expected)

I have tried to narrow this down. I need to know if the array created from a string using explode is in some way different to an array specified by $foo = array(.....). Take this code

```
   $category_array = array('Pulmonary sarcoidosis', 'Acute critical care', 'Congenital lung disease');

    foreach($category_array as $category){
                $result = Thread_category::find_all_by_category($category);
                foreach ($result as $result_array){
                echo $result_array->thread_id;
                echo "<br/>";
                }
            }

    ?>
```

Yields:

145
146
149
151

144
148
150
151

145
147
148
149
151

Which is correct. But an array created as follows...

```
    $category_array = explode(",", $thread->category);
```

Which is when outputed gives

Array ( [0] => Pulmonary sarcoidosis [1] => Acute critical care [2] => Congenital lung disease )

But when going through the foreach loop gives...

145
146
149
151

It halts as after the first loop......

No idea why and been on this for hours outputting everything.....

I understand there is code in here I haven't explained but I think the problem has to be occuring at the explode level....please help!

Comment: Please don't repost questions.

Comment: You sure you category array doesn't have leading/trailing spaces as well as commas? Maybe try `$category_array = array_map('trim', explode(",", $thread->category));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this and tell us what the echo counts say, please.

```
$category_array = explode(",","Pulmonary sarcoidosis,Acute critical care,Congenital lung disease");

echo "category_array has ".count($category_array);

foreach($category_array as $category){
            $result = Thread_category::find_all_by_category($category);
            echo "result variable has ".count($result); 
            foreach ($result as $result_array){
            echo $result_array->thread_id;
            echo "<br/>";
            }
        }

?>
```

Comment: category_array has 3

result variable has 4

145

146

149

151

result variable has 4

144

148

150

151

result variable has 5

145

147

148

149

151

Comment: Its the white space. $thread-category gives.....Pulmonary sarcoidosis, Acute critical care, Congenital lung disease. When the preceding white space is removed it works. I change the explode statement to     $category_array = explode(", ", $thread->category);

Comment: Glad you solved it. You can also use trim($mystring) to remove leading and trailing whitespaces.

Comment: Just posted the added line I needed....you are a star...pissed off it took 4 hours to work this out. When I compared the two arrays using === the result said they were equal so I was really thrown off....cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that asking for

```
 Thread_category::find_all_by_category($category);
```

where $category is a non-existing category, does not result in a server-error?

If so, I guess you are having more data in $thread->category than you expect!

Comment: I can see what you mean, but I have tested this will several different values for $category_array and in all cases it hits grinds to a halt after the first loop (which is done correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution....

White space preceding each value in the array was the issue. Therefore the solution is

```
    $category_array = explode(",", $thread->category);
    $category_array=array_map('trim',$category_array);
    foreach($category_array as $category){
        $result = Thread_category::find_all_by_category($category);
        foreach ($result as $result_array){
        echo $result_array->thread_id;
        echo "<br/>";
        }
        echo "<hr/>";
    }
```